# RSpec - unable to get all associate attributes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications, rspec

Hello Programmers & Developers!!!, I'm a beginner in RoR and creating a simple project in rails to learn its working, so in that project I'm facing a problem in writing a spec for the `create` method of controller. When I'm trying to pass the associate attributes of the object in spec file, in controller it isn't get all the attributes.

In the `create` method of `subjects_controller.rb` file.
I've created a variable called `attr` in this variable I'm storing all the values sent from `subjects_controller_spec.rb` file.

```
attr=(params.require(:subject).permit(:name)).merge(:classroom_ids=>params[:subject][:classroom_ids],:school_ids=>params[:subject][:school_ids])
```

Now, If I print the value of the `attr` using `p attr` in console it's output is the exact output that I want, which is

```
{"name"=>"Computer", "classroom_ids"=>["1", "2"], "school_ids"=>["1"]}
```

But, now I'm doing `@subject = Subject.new(attr)` and printing value of `@subject` gives the following output

```
#<Subject id: nil, name: "Computer", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

and after running the test I'm getting my test failed and then I printed the error `p @subject.errors` it gave me the below output

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fc35444a218 @base=#<Subject id: nil, name: "Computer", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:school_ids=>["is not a number"], :classroom_ids=>["is not a number"]}>
```

**So, here is my actual question is why *`@subject`* in `subjects_controller.rb` is not having values of *`classroom_ids`* and *`school_ids`***? If any solution or suggestion is there then please help me to sort out this problem.

*Below I'm providing you all the necessary details to understand the actual problem*.

**Ruby Version** `2.2.4`
**Rails Version** `4.2.0`
**Database** `MySQL`

Model file ***subject.rb***

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students

  validates_presence_of :name, :school_ids, :classroom_ids
  validates_numericality_of :school_ids, :classroom_ids
end
```

Controller file **subjects_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SubjectsController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    @school1 = FactoryGirl.create(:school)
    @classroom1 = FactoryGirl.create(:classroom, :school_id=>@school1.id)
    @classroom2 = FactoryGirl.create(:classroom, :school_id=>@school1.id)
    @subject = FactoryGirl.build(:subject)
    @subject.classrooms<<@classroom1
    @subject.classrooms<<@classroom2
    @subject.schools<<@school1
  end
  context "POST create" do
    it "should be success" do
      # p @subject
      # p @subject.classrooms
      # p @subject.classroom_ids
      attributes=@subject.attributes.merge(:classroom_ids=>@subject.classroom_ids,:school_ids=>@subject.school_ids)

      # In below line, I'm sending all the values to the controller to create a new subject.

      post :create, :subject=>attributes

      response.status.should eq 201
    end
  end
end
```

Controller file **subjects_controller.rb**

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subject, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /subjects
  def index
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end

  # GET /subjects/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /subjects/new
  def new
    @subject = Subject.new
  end

  # GET /subjects/1/edit
  def edit
  end



  # POST /subjects
  def create
    attr=(params.require(:subject).permit(:name)).merge(:classroom_ids=>params[:subject][:classroom_ids],:school_ids=>params[:subject][:school_ids])

    p attr ### here it prints all the values which I want to create subject.###

    @subject = Subject.new(attr)

    p @subject ### here is the actual problem, It's not printing all the values that need to create a new subject.###

    if @subject.save
      redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Subject was successfully created.', status: :created
    else
      p @subject.errors
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end



  # PATCH/PUT /subjects/1
  def update
    if @subject.update(subject_params)
      redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Subject was successfully updated.', status: :ok
    else
      render :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /subjects/1
  def destroy
    @subject.destroy
    redirect_to subjects_url, notice: 'Subject was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_subject
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def subject_params
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :school_ids, :classroom_ids)
    end
end
```

Factory file **subjects.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subject do
    name "Computer"
  end
end
```

RSpec **Test Report**

```
rspec spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb 
{"name"=>"Computer", "classroom_ids"=>["1", "2"], "school_ids"=>["1"]}
#<Subject id: nil, name: "Computer", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fcdfe8f1a28 @base=#<Subject id: nil, name: "Computer", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:school_ids=>["is not a number"], :classroom_ids=>["is not a number"]}>
F

Failures:

  1) SubjectsController POST create should be success
     Failure/Error: response.status.should eq 201

       expected: 201
            got: 422

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from /Users/vishal/project/school_system/spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 0.40113 seconds (files took 3.03 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb:14 # SubjectsController POST create should be success

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/vishal/project/school_system/coverage. 49 / 332 LOC (14.76%) covered.
```

For more details you can refer [this Github link](https://github.com/vishalnagda1/stack).

Thanks For Help In Advance.

Comment: What is the value of `@subject.classroom_ids`?

Comment: @ruby_newbie when I print in _subjects_controller_spec.rb_ `@subject.classroom_ids` it gives me `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ "1", "2" ] is not array of integer but String! @subject has classroom_ids and school_ids, but params always treat input values as String, so validation error occurs in your Subject model. So try below to transform String to Integer:

```
params[:subject][:classroom_ids].map(&:to_i) 
params[:subject][:school_ids].map(&:to_i)
```

How about this?

restore below without map method in the controller:

```
params[:subject][:classroom_ids] 
params[:subject][:school_ids]
```

In my PC, by modifing the Subject model as below from your github link and passed the test. 
Could you try this?

```
Class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students

  validates_presence_of :name, :school_ids, :classroom_ids
  validate :validate_classroom_ids
  validate :validate_school_ids

  private

  def validate_classroom_ids
    if classroom_ids.any?{ |id| !id.is_a?(Integer) }
      errors.add(:classroom_ids, 'is not a number')
      return false
    end
  end

  def validate_school_ids
    if school_ids.any?{ |id| !id.is_a?(Integer) }
      errors.add(:school_ids, 'is not a number')
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: as you said I updated it

`attr=(params.require(:subject).permit(:name)).merge(:classroom_ids=>params[:subject][:classroom_ids].map(&:to_i),:school_ids=>params[:subject][:school_ids].map(&:to_i))`

and when I'm printing it gave me

`{"name"=>"Computer", "classroom_ids"=>[1, 2], "school_ids"=>[1]} `

which is exact result but still it's not working. The terminal error is still same.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I guess classroom_ids and school_ids are Array, so validation error occurs. So you should check numericality of each member of these.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to do that?

Comment: got `NoMethodError:
       undefined method match for 1:Fixnum`

please refer this [Github link](https://github.com/vishalnagda1/stack), so you can get more exact details.

Comment: OK, I will check your github link after I get home, because I can't clone your project right now . And could you try !id.match(/¥d+/) to !id.is_a?(Integer) ?Do you still fail tests?

Comment: I edited the answer, running spec and passed in my PC.